# C Makefile exercises from HeadFirst C

Tags: c, makefile

I am learning C from Head First C. One  short exercise is connected with Makefile. The source code is:

```
oggswing: oggswing.c oggswing.h
   gcc oggswing.c -o oggswing

swing.ogg: whitennerdy.ogg oggswing
   oggswing whitennerdy.ogg swing.ogg
```

*(Please assume that the indented lines start with the required tab.)*

I do not understand  `oggswing whitennerdy.ogg swing.ogg`. There isn’t any command like `gcc` or the other.  I can't find any solutions why is that correct? Could you help me?

Comment: Please [edit] using info from help on formatting, to make the code correctly displayed.

Comment: `oggswing whitennerdy.ogg swing.ogg` *is* the command.

Answer (score 1):

`oggswing` is the result of building oggswing.c. 
It can then be executed to process the two .ogg files (in whatever way it implements).
And oggswing will be built because it is a dependency for the target swing.ogg.